# TS callback function parameters seem to be incompletely checked

Tags: typescript

TS accepts a callback function that requires a subclass of the type that it will be called with, but not a completely separate type.

This seems like a bug to me, what gives?

pseudo:

```
class A ...
class B extends A ...
class C ...
callWithA((a:A)=>void) ...
takeB(b:B) ...
takeC(c:C) ...
callWithA(takeB) // compiles fine, but will break at runtime
callWithA(takeC) // does not compile
```

Full example:

```js
class A {
    a: string;
}
class B extends A {
    b: string;
}
class C {
    c: string;
}
function callWithA(callbackfn: (value: A) => void): void {
    callbackfn(new A());
}
function callWithB(callbackfn: (value: B) => void): void {
    callbackfn(new B());
}

function takeA(a: A) {
    console.log('takeA got', a);
    console.log('#');
}

function takeB(b: B) {
    console.log('takeB got', b);
    console.log('#');
}

function takeC(c: C) {
    console.log('takeC got', c);
    console.log('#');
}

function takeString(s: String) {
    console.log('takeString got', s);
    console.log('#');
}

let a: A
a = new B();
let b: B;
// b = new A(); // incompatible, Good!
// takeB(new A()); // incompatible, Good!

callWithA(takeA); // takeA(a:A) will be called with an A, OK
callWithA(takeB); // BUG HERE ?! takeB(b:B) will be called with an A!! not good!
// callWithA(takeC); // incompatible, good, A is not a C
// callWithA(takeString); // incompatible, good

callWithB(takeA); // takeA(a:A) will be called with a B, OK
callWithB(takeB); // takeB(b:B) will be called with a B, OK
  // callWithB(takeC); // incompatible, good, A is not a C
  // callWithB(takeString); // incompatible, good
```

I would expect the compiler to refuse to use the incompatible callback 'takeB'

I have seen that TS does accept calling functions with subclass of the required arguments, which can cause problems:

```js
addDog(arr: Animal[]) {arr.append(new Dog())}
let cats: Cat[] = []
addDog(cats) // Works, since cats are animals, but then we get dogs in a array of cats
```

But this seems different, and calling the callback directly does not compile.

Is this a bug, or 'By Design'.?

Comment: A `B` is an `A`, so, this looks correct to me.

Comment: `strictFunctionTypes` is the flag you are looking for

Comment: @ExplosionPills Except that takeB() will be called with an A, which has none of the attributes that are specific to B, which takeB() expects to exist. It will then crash at runtime. As others have pointed out, strictFunctionTypes helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default function parameters are bivariantly. There is a compiler flag that will make this an error and it's called `strictFunctionTypes`. With this flag the call you highlight will be an error.

You can read more about it [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/18654)

Comment: Thanks, that catches the problem!